# How did 賃 get its 慣用音 reading?

Tags: etymology

賃 has the 慣用音 reading ちん, as in 家賃{やちん}.

I understand that a lot of 慣用音 readings arise from interpreting the phonetic wrongly (for example 消耗{しょうこう} vs 消耗{しょうもう}), but in this case how did 賃 receive the reading ちん?

I'm having trouble seeing how it could be connected to ちん, when the 呉音 and 漢音 are にん and じん respectively.

Comment: Not an answer, more of a musing -- I see over at [the Japanese Wiktionary entry](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/賃#日本語) that the 漢音 of じん derived from older ぢむ.  I wonder if ちん arose via a devoicing of that same older form?

Answer (score 2):

[This thesis (note: pdf will download)](https://seitoku.repo.nii.ac.jp/?action=repository_action_common_download&item_id=195&item_no=1&attribute_id=20&file_no=2) seems to give a taxonomy of 慣用音. And acutally Eiríkr Útlendi's conjecture is  correct (or no other way to justify it). 賃 is categorized as an example of 漢音の清音化 （ぢん →　ちん）on p137.

慣用音 means after all 'the way it is pronounced', and how they arise may not be unique and ultimately unkonwn.